# Why is the 'else' statement appearing in the output?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and was experimenting with this program when I ran into a hiccup. Not a technical one, that is. The program ran just fine.

```
#include<iostream>    
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int num1, num2;
    char ch;
    cout << "Enter the two integers: ";
    cin >> num1 >> num2;
    cout << "Choose one of the following arithmetic operators: " << endl;
    cout << "+" << endl;
    cout << "-" << endl;
    cout << "*" << endl;
    cout << "/" << endl;
    cin >> ch;
    if (ch == '+')
        cout << "The sum of the two numbers is: " << num1 + num2 << endl;
    if (ch == '-')
        cout << num2 << " subtracted from " << num1 << " is " << num1 - num2 << endl;
    if (ch == '*')
        cout << "When multiplied: " << num1*num2 << endl;
    if (ch == '/')
        cout << num1 << " divided by " << num2 << " will be " << num1 / num2 << endl;
    else
        cout << "Wrong input. Try again.";
    return 0;
}
```

Now here's the problem. When the if-statement is satisfied, along with provided calculation, the output also shows the statement from the else-statement. 
I tried editing the else to:-

```
else if(ch=!'+','-','*','/')
```

and

```
if(ch=!'+','-','*','/')
```

but none of them seem to work. In all the cases, "Wrong input. Try again." somehow finds its way to the output. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: That last 'if' with the commas is actually equivalent to `if(ch != '/')`. Read up on the comma operator in C/C++

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your entire structure needs to be `if`-`else if`-`else`, like so:

```
if(ch=='+')
    cout<<"The sum of the two numbers is: "<<num1+num2<<endl;
else if(ch=='-')
    cout<<num2<<" subtracted from "<<num1<<" is "<<num1-num2<<endl;
else if(ch=='*')
    cout<<"When multiplied: "<<num1*num2<<endl;
else if(ch=='/')
    cout<<num1<<" divided by "<<num2<<" will be "<<num1/num2<<endl;
else 
    cout<<"Wrong input. Try again.";
```

But is this the best way to do things? Probably not. Since you're just testing to see what `ch` is equal to, you can actually make use of another built-in C++ construct, the `switch` statement:

```
switch (ch) {
  case '+':
    cout << "The sum of the two numbers is: " << num1+num2 << endl;
    break;
  case '-':
    cout << num2 << " subtracted from " << num1 << " is " << num1-num2 << endl;
    break;
  case '*':
    cout << "When multiplied: " << num1*num2 << endl;
    break;
  case '/':
    cout << num1 << " divided by " << num2 << " will be " << num1/num2 << endl;
    break;
  default:
    cout << "Wrong input. Try again." << endl;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In your original code, the `else` only applies to the last `if` statement. You need to chain your conditions:

```
if(ch=='+')
    cout<<"The sum of the two numbers is: "<<num1+num2<<endl;
else if(ch=='-')
    cout<<num2<<" subtracted from "<<num1<<" is "<<num1-num2<<endl;
else if(ch=='*')
    cout<<"When multiplied: "<<num1*num2<<endl;
else if(ch=='/')
    cout<<num1<<" divided by "<<num2<<" will be "<<num1/num2<<endl;
else 
    cout<<"Wrong input. Try again.";
```

However, you are probably better off using a `switch` statement:

```
switch (ch) {
case '+':
    cout<<"The sum of the two numbers is: "<<num1+num2<<endl;
    break;
case '-';
    cout<<num2<<" subtracted from "<<num1<<" is "<<num1-num2<<endl;
    break;
case '*':
    cout<<"When multiplied: "<<num1*num2<<endl;
    break;
case '/':
    cout<<num1<<" divided by "<<num2<<" will be "<<num1/num2<<endl;
    break;
default:
    cout<<"Wrong input. Try again."; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`else` part will always be executed when `ch` is not equal to `/` because the else part is matched to `if(ch=='/')` only.Probably you want to use if else ladder or switch case.

Answer (score 0):

The "Else-statement" is linked with the last "if-statement". So, if the non last if-statement avaliates to true, then the last one will avaliate to false, and this implies on true avaliation to else-statement. You can change your if-statement to "else if" (don't chage the first if-statement).